# Partial derivative of a loss function

Tags: derivatives, machine-learning

I am having trouble making the jump from my understanding to a given solution. Given the equation:

$E_D = \frac12 (t - \sum_{i=1}^n \delta_iw_iI_i)^2$

I factor this out to:

$\frac{\partial E_D}{\partial w_i} = \frac12 (t - \sum_{i=1}^n \delta_iw_iI_i)^2 = -t\delta_iI_i+\delta_iI_i\sum_{i=1}^n\delta_iw_iI_i$

But the answer I am given is:

$\frac{\partial E_D}{\partial w_i} = \frac12 (t - \sum_{i=1}^n \delta_iw_iI_i)^2 = -t\delta_iI_i+ w_i\delta_i^2I_i^2 + \sum_{j=1,j\ne i}^n\delta_i\delta_jI_iI_jw_i$

I am not sure what I am missing, can anyone help?

Comment: Your answer is the same as the answer given, just take the $i^{th}$ term out of your series and put it into a $w_i \delta_i^2 I_i^2$ term, then you have left $\sum_{j=1, j \neq i}^n \delta_i \delta_j I_i I_j w_i$

Comment: Ah, I see thank you I didn't see that's what he was doing. It is not clear why this is the case though.

Comment: happy to answer a question on it